# Why wont my onclick not remove any of my classes?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a huge problem here.
I can't get my onclick to work as I want .. So I hope someone here can help me.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('nice').style.display='none';" class="sorter">#NiceToKnow</a>

<div id="cards" class="nice"></div>
<div id="cards" class="nice"></div>
<div id="cards" class="nice"></div>
<div id="cards" class="video"></div>
```

I want it to display: none; every of my class="nice", so you only can see class="video", but nothing happens at all.

Comment: it return array of element  document.getElementsByClassName('nice') so use for loop to hide all element which have "nice" class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are selecting the elements of the class not the class itself. So you will have to loop through the elements as javascript can only edit what is in the DOM not the CSS classes that effect your elements. So getElementsByClassName returns an array of nodes in which we must loop through and hide each one. Click runsnippet below to see this work

```js
function changeNice(){
//ASSIGN ELEMENTS TO ARRAY
elementsofClass=document.getElementsByClassName('nice');
for(i=0; i<elementsofClass.length; i++){
    //HIDE SELECTED ELEMENT
    elementsofClass[i].style.display='none';
  
  
}}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="changeNice();" class="sorter">#NiceToKnow</a>

<div id="cards1" class="nice">TEST 1</div>
<div id="cards2" class="nice">TEST 2</div>
<div id="cards3" class="nice">TEST 3</div>
<div id="cards4" class="video">I don't HIDE</div>
```

Also don't use duplicate ID. This will cause errors later when trying to select your elements.

Answer (score 2):

The `getElementsByClassName` will return an array, so we need to iterate through the array and hide one by one.

So it is better to declare a function and define the logic inside that. Please see the example below.

```js
window.hideAllniceClass = function () {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('nice');
    for (var i = 0; i != elems.length; ++i) {
        elems[i].style.display = "none"; // hidden has to be a string
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="hideAllniceClass();" class="sorter">#NiceToKnow</a>

<div id="cards1" class="nice">Test Content</div>
<div id="cards2" class="nice">Test Content</div>
<div id="cards3" class="nice">Test Content</div>
<div id="cards4" class="video">Test Video Content</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/n04we848/)

Comment: Yup that's the code, but to help the asker understand, can you explain what your code is doing?

Comment: Thanks @JoshKG ! Kindly let me know if the updated answer helpful :)

Comment: @KishoreSahas I would recommend either removing the id attributes or making them unique rather than showing poor syntax.

Comment: Thanks @PC3TJ , I appreciate your comments , it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to something like that:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('nice');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'none'
}
```

You have to iterate on the results returned by getElementsByClassName.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmj3vesj/#)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a loop that will loop through all the `nice` elements and then display `none` like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/7vf9pz8u/

```
<script>
    function hide(){
    for(ct=0; ct < 3; ct++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('nice')[ct].style.display='none'
    }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**getElementsByClassName** returns array of all the match elements so you will have to provide index or loop through all of them to change their property.

Change your code to this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('nice')[0].style.display='none'
```

//For every element

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('nice');
for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  e[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only select the 1st element? He wants all elements.

Comment: @JoshKG that what i told to loop through every element, But check my update

Answer (score -2):

As your divs do not have unique names they are in an array cards[].
So to access a particular div you need to reference the the array to that particular div. The quoted solution should work.

Comment: They do not need to have a unique name as they can be selected by there class name, then looped through the array such as every other answer. Addressing these divs by a unique name would just drastically complicate the problem.

Comment: Unless  you are speaking of there ID which the OP has all duplicated as addressed in my answer that of course is poor syntax, however; doesn't effect the results in this particular problem.